# Order By Column Names

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to use the names of the actual columns for the order by clause?

I am using a view to let a client use a reporter writer (Pentaho) and this would make things easier on them.

To clarify, I want to  put the results in alphabetical order of the column names themselves.  I want to sort the data using the columns, not the data IN the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can try:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 
 'my_table' ORDER BY column_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is to change the order of the columns themselves according to their names (that would make sense only if you are using `SELECT *`, I guess), I'm afraid that's not possible, at least not straightforwardly. And that sounds very unSQL, I'd say...

Comment: True, I guess I'll have to specify each column in the order I want them in my query.  ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can order by column name, column alias, or column position:

select a, b from table order by b;

select a as x, b as y from table order by x, y;

select a, b from table order by 1;

Comment: I was not clear, sorry.  Please see edit above.  I want to sort by names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the view with the columns in any order you like. Then `SELECT * FROM your_view` queries will return the columns in the order specified by the view.

Comment: yeah, i figured i would have to do this.